# Convert unicode representations on incoming string to UTF-8?

Tags: java, utf-8

I'm reading some data that has already been converted to html style υ code.

I now need to convert this back to UTF-8 characters for viewing.  Unfortunately I can't use a browser to view the string.

I've read around about conversion in java and it seems if you have a string of \uxxxx then the compiler will convert for you; However that wont work of course because I want to read in dynamic strings.

So can this be done?

Many thanks!
Dan

Comment: What’s “html style u code”? The “\uxxxx” notation has nothing to do with HTML.

Comment: that should have read ambersand hash x x x.  not "u code"!

Comment: I've also discivered the unescapeHTML call which is also handy for named entity refs like &amp;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use:

```
String StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(String str)
```

from the Apache Commons Library.

It will find `\uxxxx` sequences in the input string and convert them to a normal Java String.

Answer (score 0):

[native2ascii](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/native2ascii.html)

Use the "-reverse" option.

Answer (score 0):

> converted to html style υ code.

Which of those? `\uXXXX` is a Java convention and has nothing to do with HTML. HTML entities look like `&#175;`

Comment: both; 

The way to do it is to convert &#xxx; to \uxxxx and then to convert that to UTF-8 using apache commons.