# Is there a better way to convert a String containing UTF-8 byte code to a UTF-8 string?

Tags: java, utf-8

I have a String that contains `"\u0627\u0644\u0628\u062d\u0631\u0649\u0646"`.

I would like to convert to a String that contains `"البحرىن"`.

I tried using this method, but it does not do what I hoped it would:

```
protected String convertUtf(String input) throws CharacterCodingException {
   Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
   CharsetDecoder decoder = charset.newDecoder();
   CharsetEncoder encoder = charset.newEncoder();
   ByteBuffer bbuf = encoder.encode(CharBuffer.wrap(input));
   CharBuffer cbuf = decoder.decode(bbuf);
   return cbuf.toString();
}
```

Thoughts?

Comment: I don't think that that's what "byte code" means. But when it comes to text encoding, everyone seems to love making up their own words anyway...

Comment: Are you saying that the original String contains a sequence of 7 unicode escapes, each 6 characters long, so `orig.length() == 42`?

Comment: Ok, sorry for using incorrect terminology.  What I am trying to do is print out a string that is readable, when what I have is the UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: Internally Strings are always UTF-8 so there is nothing to convert. Except when the String contains the literals "\u0627..." like Stephen assumes.

Comment: Stephen P - Yes.  That is exactly what I have.  A String of 7 unicode escapes (length = 42).  Thank you for helping me make that clear.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, @gras has the _literal_ string "\\u0627", which is a string with six distinct characters.  He wants to do the Unicode substitution at runtime, not compile-time.

Comment: I don't know if there are runtime parsers. `java.util.Properties`, which can handle unicode literal sequences, does a manual conversion in `private String loadConvert (char[] in, int off, int len, char[] convtBuf)` (as of 1.6.0.26).

Comment: A runtime parser is what I am looking for.  The input String is created using `substring()` from a longer String.  (Also, the code snippet in the original question does not do what I was hoping it would...)

Comment: If your situation is as @LouisWasserman implies, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/672948/convert-unicode-representations-on-incoming-string-to-utf-8)

Comment: Oh, Apache Commons, that is better. What a surprise ;-).

Comment: @KevinK, that's worth posting as an answer.

Comment: @KevinK, the link you posted is exactly what I am looking for!  If you post an answer as Louis Wasserman suggests I would be thrilled to acknowledge your wisdom.  Thanks to all who helped lead me to this solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For converting a string with literal codepoints (e.g. `String s = "\\u0627[...]"`), see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672948/convert-unicode-representations-on-incoming-string-to-utf-8).

Answer (score 3):

It's the same thing. The two forms are interchangeable. It's simply a different way of representing the string in java code. The `String` object is the same. For example:

```
String s1 = "\u0627\u0644\u0628\u062d\u0631\u0649\u0646";
String s2 = "البحرىن";

System.out.println(s1.equals(s2)); //prints "true"
```

Comment: I understand that these two Strings are "equal", but on my system `System.out.println(s1);` displays `\u0627\u0644\u0628\u062d\u0631\u0649\u0646`.  What do I need to do to display a foreign language?

Comment: Make your console support UTF-8, I guess. But even if it doesn't, it shouldn't print sequences. On my machine it prints the arabic letters.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the *literal* String "\u0627\u0644\u0628\u062d\u0631\u0649\u0646" and want to convert it to the correct Unicode string then you have to do the parsing / conversion by hand. You can find the method for this in `String java.util.Properties#loadConvert (char[] in, int off, int len, char[] convtBuf)`. As it is `private` you can't use it from outside but have to copy it.